# PL-SQL to_date with timezone

Tags: plsql

Is there a way to simply convert string date as 
`2018-02-15T14:00:00+01:00` to oracle date?

I tried with to_date and `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS+01:00'` format but it is not valid

Oracle always thrown 'date format not recognized'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-02-15T14:00:00+01:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"+"TZH:TZM') as date) from dual;
```

oracle date has not time zone information. You have to convert it into timestamp with time zone and cast it as date (losing accuracy)